# Webstart Chrome After 100th Download

Tags: java, google-chrome, jnlp, java-web-start

We have a java application that our customers launch via webstart.
We have some usability problems with it :

Up to hundred clicks on the link for the jnlp file, "chrome" simply downloads the jnlp file, names it incrementally : index(1).jnlp, index(2).jsp, etc. and launces the application. But after 100 downloads, when the user clicks on the link, chrome opens a "save as" dialog. Then the user clicks on save; and chrome asks "This file already exists, do you really want to replace it?" And the user says yes, and chrome downloads the jnlp etc.

This process creates usability problems. To avoid it we started changing the name of the jnlp file regularly. But when users click on the new jnlp link for the first time, chrome asks "This type of file can harm your computer. Do you want to keep .......jnlp anyway?" before downloading the file. And this creates another step of clicking another button. And of course it scares the user.

In spite of chrome's problematic handling of the issue, Firefox smoothly continues incrementing file name number after 100.

How can we solve this problem with chrome, without asking the user do some complicated adjustments in their computers?

Comment: Please star the following issue on the Chromium bug tracker so that the team knows that you are interested in getting this fixed in Chrome https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=92846

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the JNLP install a desktop shortcut & menu items.  That way, they only need to 'download the JNLP' once!

[image]

The 2 icons on the right ([JotPad](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#eis) & Star Zoom Animation) are both Java based apps., installed using Java Web Start.  Since JotPad is sand-boxed, the user will be prompted as to whether to create the shortcut.  That choice is not offered for apps. with higher permission levels, so it would make more sense to install/remove the shortcuts and menu items using the [`IntegrationService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/IntegrationService.html) - which allows an app. (after prompting the user) to create/remove them at run-time.

Comment: (1-) What happens when we modify the jnlp file on our web site?
Then will the user continue using the old version of the jnlp file?
(2-) Still we don't like this way. Because : 
    (a.) We like the user access our home page, where the jnlp link resides.
    (b.) Even if we let them create a shortcut, not all users will use the shortcut. And the ones that use Chrome will still have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Easy. Just tell them to change their download options so that it asks where to save each time, then tell them to remember the path name. The next time they want to launch the app, they can just open the already-downloaded JNLP rather than downloading it again. Or, tell them to use a browser like Internet Explorer or Opera that download to a temporary folder instead of saving the file each time.

Comment: Telling the customer that they should use IE or Firefox but not Chrome is not a good solution. One of the reasons that we use JAVA is to be away from the browser incompatibilities.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem this way :
Once in a month I rename the JNLP file, and modify the html file that contains the JNLP link, of course.
In 30 days, it is unlikely that the user clicks on and downloads the JNLP link more than 100 times.